# ePub reader api For iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c

is there any ePub reader API available for iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Epub is essentially HTML. So you can either use UIWebView for displaying it or use a Framework or an Open Source component like https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML to implement your own rendering.